# How to do index lookup (word2idx) in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Suppose I have a word2idx dict with 1000 words:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, ..., 'zzz': 999}
```

and map OOVs to 1000.

I wanted to do this lookup in Tensorflow 2, e.g., given

```
text = tf.ragged.constant([["a", "b"], ["zzz"], ["abcd"]])
```

The result would be

```
indices = tf.ragged.constant([[0, 1], [999], [1000]])
```

How am I able to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tf.ragged.map_flat_values`:

```
text = tf.ragged.constant([[["a", "b"], ["zzz"], ["c",'N']]])
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'zzz': 999, 'z':8}
OOV_CODE = 1000
lookup = lambda x: [d.get(key.numpy().decode("utf-8"), OOV_CODE) for key in x]
indices = tf.ragged.map_flat_values(lookup, text)
    
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[0, 1], [999], [2, 1000]]]>
```

for vectorized TF-only way consider `tf.lookup` tools:

```
    d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'zzz': 999, 'z':8}
    t = tf.ragged.constant([["a", "b"], ["zzz"], ["c"], ['N','M']])
    
    ti = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
                list(d.keys()), list(d.values()), key_dtype=None, value_dtype=tf.int64, name=None)
    
    lu = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(ti, num_oov_buckets = 1 )
    
    tf.ragged.map_flat_values(lu.lookup, t)

<tf.RaggedTensor [[0, 1], [999], [2], [5, 5]]>
```

note that it uses `5` as OOV value - apparently it is the smallest free positive value. If you feed values 0-999 as in your example, OOV code will naturally be 1000.

Comment: How could this handle OOV issue?

Comment: easy: just use dict.get with OOV code as default value. see example updated,

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. But this will force a tensor to be converted to numpy which is time consuming. Is there anyway we could do it in tf/keras naive api?

Comment: check out  solution with `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable()` above